how is sum of user and system space time more than clock?
I knew that time(1) reports the time taken to run something in User Space, Kernel Space. In addition, it also shows the wall clock time. The latter is approximately the sum of the previous two.
When I look at the Figure 15.29 on Advanced Programming in the UNIX Environment. It compares the time taken for several ways of utilizing shared resource. I noticed the Clock is not the sum of the User and System. .
It would be reasonable if the Clock is slightly larger than the sum of User and System, because the time of context switching is not measured (maybe?), but the second row states that Clock time is far less than the sum of the two.
Either the author is not using time(1) for the benchmark, or I misunderstood the concept.
Can someone explain?

"User" and "System" time are the time the program is active on a single core.  "Clock" time, on the other hand is wall clock time for all cores.  So when running on a multicore machine, you can easily get cases where the sum of "User" and "System" time is more than the "Clock" time -- it just means you are using multiple cores simultaneously.  On the other hand, when "Clock" is larger, that means that cores are spending time idle.

Thanks for the explanation. Does that imply the (user & system) time return for x unit of work running on multiple cores is more than it would be when running on a single core? I am trying to follow. Say, x unit of works are distributed to n CPUs, the total time taken is then n * (x / n) which is still x (same as running the work on a single core). How could using multiple cores simultaneously adds up more than single core?

Your program is not running 100% of the time - it is spending time waiting for resources, or pre-empted by other runnable processes (and the time spent waiting for resources is the key point of this example).
Conversely, running times (user+system) can exceed the elapsed ("clock") time when a process is running on multiple CPUs simultaneously.
